# Facing issue in replace string in a file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file which contains below data

```
mkdir language
```

Here is my vbscript which replace language string in text file

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "language", "english,french,spanish")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

I am getting output mkdir english,french,spanish but what i want output in text file as shown below

```
mkdir english
mkdir french
mkdir spanish
```

How to achieve this please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work too...

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim langs
langs = Array("english","french","spanish")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
tempTxt = ""
strNewText = ""
For Each i in langs
    tempTxt = "mkdir " + i + vbCrLf
    strNewText = strNewText + tempTxt
Next

strNewText = Replace(strText, "mkdir language", strNewText)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("Text.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this variation:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Scripts\Text.txt", ForWriting)

For Each strLanguage In Array("english", "french", "spanish")
    objFile.WriteLine Replace(strText, "language", strLanguage)
Next

objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yscc53h0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to build a string from an array:

```
>> c = "mkdir "
>> l = Split("english,french,spanish", ",")
>> WScript.Echo c & Join(l, vbCrLf & c)
>>
mkdir english
mkdir french
mkdir spanish
```

Of course, `c` could come from a file.

(But I suspect your real world problem isn't shown in your simplified sample)